# What is the number of ways of expressing 4 as the sum of 5 nonnegative integers?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I read a book and it says that this is equivalent to putting 4 balls in the 5 numbered baskets, thus the answer is 70 by the combination with repetitions. However I think it is ridiculously wrong because so many repetitions arise from this method. For example one ball in the first basket and 3 balls in the third basket is differently counted from three balls in the first basket and one ball in the third basket. However, both are just 0+0+0+1+3. So I am curious what the real answer is. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Your book might think that $0+0+0+1+3$ is a different sum from $3+0+0+0+1$.

Comment: Then what is the answer if the summation order does not matter?

Comment: The answer in the book is the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 4$ in the nonnegative integers.

Comment: If the summation order does not matter, you are describing a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).  There are $5$ partitions of $4$ into five nonnegative integers.

Comment: Partitions are notoriously difficult to count in general. Some times you get constraints which make the counting easier (like "at most three parts"), and some times you get constraints that do not help much, or possibly even make it more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid repetitions, there are only **5 ways** : $4=4$, $4=3+1$, $4=2+2$, $4=2+1+1$, $4=1+1+1+1$. And add zeros to these equalities to get a sum of 5 non-negative numbers.

If you allow repetitions, $4=4$ gives 5 solutions (5 positions for the 4), $4=3+1$ gives $2{5 \choose 2}$ solutions, $4=2+2$ gives $5 \choose 2$ possibilities, $4=1+1+1+1$ gives 5 possibilities and finally $4=1+1+2$ leads to $5 \times {4 \choose 2}$ choices. This gives finally $5+20+10+5+5\times6=70$ different possibilities.